# how to export VM (VirtualBox) to tgz archive?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-container

I'm trying to use docker import to get VM in a container, but the required format is "image.tgz", is it possible to export a VM image from VirtualBox to ".tgz" format?

Comment: you can export to tar format and then further converty it to .tgz? Isn't it ok?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Docker internally does not use VirtualBox, and therefore won't be able to load a VirtualBox image. You're probably using VirtualBox due to using Docker-Machine...

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: I think you are confusing VMs and containers.  The virtualbox disk image contains the full OS (including kernel).  You can't "import" this into Docker.  Even if you could tar and compress the disk image it would be an invalid file.

Comment: thx guys, in my case I have CentOS in a virtual machine that I created using virtualBox, It has its own configuration. I need to have this machine under docker container and I want to keep the same configuration. for example using this command : sudo tar -c . | docker import - exampleimagedir